# Should I evaluate topic coherence of topic model on test set?

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm a newbie in topic models. From my understanding, topic models like latent dirichlet allocation (LDA) (without empirical Bayes on hyperparameters) performs variational inference to approximate the posterior, and really it's not related to parameter estimation. **Should I, then, fit an LDA on training set, fix the topic-word distribution (the $\beta$), and evaluate coherence using $\beta$ on a separate test set? If yes, why does it make sense?**

I read several papers, e.g. [(Srivastava and Sutton, 2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01488), in particular the Experiments section; but I didn't find the authors mentioning evaluate coherence on a test set. Maybe it's too common in the art to mention that... That's why I seek for clarification here.